# Is it secure to use the AspNetUsers table in a Model to display its data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, security, asp.net-identity

Ok so I have an ASP .NET MVC 5 application and I used “Identity Framework” which generates automatically the tables shown in the image.

[image: Tables]

Then I have a Database First Model which I created for the rest of the application and my question is that if it is correct and safe to also read the data of these tables and show it to the user in the webpage? (I do use ViewModels)

Comment: Your use case and environment will determine if it's correct and safe to read the data from the tables and show it to the users, but typically you don't do it that way. You generally use the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity assemblies to handle authentication in an MVC app. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-identity-in-simple-ways-using-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: yes the Identity handles the authentication of my application but I want to display all the Users and Emails of the table in a View, I just want to make sure if it is right to do so

Comment: If your use case requires you to do that, then yes, you can pull the data from the users table and display the username and email in a view. Happy to help with how to do that if needed.

Comment: Putting the same information in a different table and displaying it, doesn't make it any "better". The answer is completely use-case specific. If I was registering on an e-commerce site and found the company was displaying my name and email publicly, I'd be very upset. If I was registering on an internal on-call register within my employers company and support personnel could read a list of on-call support users with their emails that would be pretty much expected.

Comment: @agileMike ok ty for the info, and np I already know how to do that

Comment: @Ben ye I undestand what you saying but not everyone is going to be able to see it, only users with the roles of Admin are authorize to enter the Controller I'm using [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]